# Sending data from Arduino to Android

Tags: android, arduino

I have been trying to send data from arduino to an Android application via Bluetooth Module HC-05 and i couldn't get any readings from the arduino to be displayed in the application

The arduino code is :

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{
  char c;
if(Serial.available())
  {
   c = Serial.read();
   Serial.print(c);
  }
}
```

The Android code is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Handler;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    //    private final String DEVICE_NAME="MyBTBee";
    private final String DEVICE_ADDRESS="30:14:12:18:01:38";
    private final UUID PORT_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");//Serial Port Service ID
    private BluetoothDevice device;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    Button startButton, sendButton,clearButton,stopButton;
    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;
    boolean deviceConnected=false;
    Thread thread;
    byte buffer[];
    int bufferPosition;
    boolean stopThread;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonClear);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        setUiEnabled(false);

    }

    public void setUiEnabled(boolean bool)
    {
        startButton.setEnabled(!bool);
        sendButton.setEnabled(bool);
        stopButton.setEnabled(bool);
        textView.setEnabled(bool);

    }

    public boolean BTinit()
    {
        boolean found=false;
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Device doesnt Support Bluetooth",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, 0);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if(bondedDevices.isEmpty())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Pair the Device first",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            for (BluetoothDevice iterator : bondedDevices)
            {
                if(iterator.getAddress().equals(DEVICE_ADDRESS))
                {
                    device=iterator;
                    found=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }

    public boolean BTconnect()
    {
        boolean connected=true;
        try {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(PORT_UUID);
            socket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            connected=false;
        }
        if(connected)
        {
            try {
                outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        return connected;
    }

    public void onClickStart(View view) {
        if(BTinit())
        {
            if(BTconnect())
            {
                setUiEnabled(true);
                deviceConnected=true;
                beginListenForData();
                textView.append("\nConnection Opened!\n");
            }

        }
    }

    void beginListenForData()
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        stopThread = false;
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        Thread thread  = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopThread)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int byteCount = inputStream.available();
                        if(byteCount > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] rawBytes = new byte[byteCount];
                            inputStream.read(rawBytes);
                            final String string=new String(rawBytes,"UTF-8");
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    textView.append(string);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        stopThread = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

    public void onClickSend(View view) {
        String string = editText.getText().toString();
        string.concat("\n");
        try {
            outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textView.append("\nSent Data:"+string+"\n");

    }

    public void onClickStop(View view) throws IOException {
        stopThread = true;
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        socket.close();
        setUiEnabled(false);
        deviceConnected=false;
        textView.append("\nConnection Closed!\n");
    }

    public void onClickClear(View view) {
        textView.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see right now is in your Arduino code:
You're never sending the message over Bluetooth as you're using the same Serial for input and output. If you're using an Arduino Mega using Serial1 would fixe this (Using TX1 and RX1). If you're not using a Mega you should consider to use the SerialSoftware library which allows you to create a new custom Serial.

It would be nice to see your Arduino setup to see how you wired it up.

Hope that helps you, feel free to ask any question.

Comment: ya i figured that out and made my corrections...now its working fine....thanks bro